# Commit after alter table

Tags: oracle, transactions, ddl

Should I run `COMMIT;` after

```
ALTER TABLE TBL_SAMPLE ADD (BOOLEAN_COLUMN NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL);
```

in Oracle, or it is not mandatory?

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Types-of-SQL-Statements.html#GUID-FD9A8CB4-6B9A-44E5-B114-EFB8DA76FC88) "*Oracle Database implicitly commits the current transaction before and after every DDL statement*"

Comment: After command you wrote you have to **fix** it (as it is invalid).

Comment: @Littlefoot You are right. Occasionally I deleted 'NUMBER' before '(1)'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need commit after DDL.